# How To Check Value Of Input Given By Other Inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The sum of the top inputs is put into the bottom input. I need to fire some JS code if the value of the bottom input goes above 100. My code is not working as it should.

HTML

```
<div>
<input type="text" class="top" maxlength="3" value="0" />
<input type="text" class="top" maxlength="3" value="0" />
<input type="text" class="bottom" maxlength="5" value="0" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("change", ".top", function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".top").each(function () {
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".bottom").val(sum);
});

$(document).on("change", ".bottom", function () {
    var sum = $(".bottom").val();
    if (sum > 100) {
        alert("Test alert!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because programmatically updating the `value` of an `input` does not raise an event, so the `change` handler you bind is never invoked. To fix this `trigger()` an event manually after setting `val()`.

Also note there's a couple of other tweaks to the logic which can be made, such as using `this` in the `.bottom` event handler to reference the element which raised the event instead of *all* `.bottom` elements in the DOM, and also using the `input` event, which is triggered as typing occurs and also when content is pasted in using the mouse.

```js
$(document).on("input", ".top", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".top").each((i, el) => sum += +el.value);
  $(".bottom").val(sum).trigger('input');
});

$(document).on("input", ".bottom", function() {
  var sum = +$(this).val();
  if (sum > 100) {
    console.log("Test alert!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="top" maxlength="3" value="0" />
  <input type="text" class="top" maxlength="3" value="0" />
  <input type="text" class="bottom" maxlength="5" value="0" />
</div>
```